# Can't Open Display error when trying to set resolution at startup

Tags: display, cron

I connect with my Ubuntu 16.04 headless box from my Windows machine using TeamViewer 14. The default resolution is 1024X768 and this is dictated by my Linux machine.  I have finally figured out a script that will change the resolution.

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --newmode "1080p" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1080p
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1080p
```

This works perfectly when I run it from command, but when I tried making it a cron at startup (using @reboot) or putting into rc.local, I get errors "Can't open display."  Ideally, I would like for this script to run each time the system reboots so that when I connect with TeamViewer, the resolution is already set. I realize I can simply run it from a terminal each time, but what a pain. Of course, with all the time I've invested in this already, that would have been easier.....